# Save multiple checkbox value to database in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, html, checkbox, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using checkboxes to save data in database. It can save only one value at a time. When multiple values are selected, it only stores the first selected value.

Code-

- ViewModel:

```cs
public class CreatePostViewModel
{
    // Code before
    
    // Category
    public string? CollectionCategory { get; set; }

    // Category List
    public List<CollectionCategoryModel>? CollectionCategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

- Controller:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync()
{
    // Category List
    var CreatePostCategoryVM = new CreatePostViewModel
    {
        CollectionCategoryList = await _context.CollectionCategories.ToListAsync()
    };

    return View(CreatePostCategoryVM);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreatePostViewModel postVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var post = new PostModel
        {
            // Code before             

            // Category
            CollectionCategory = postVM.CollectionCategory,
        };

         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        // Error
    }
    return View(postVM);
}
```

- View:

```html
<div class="form-check">
    @foreach (var list in Model.CollectionCategoryList)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="CollectionCategory" id="@list.CategoryName" value="@list.CategoryName">
        <label asp-for="CollectionCategory" for="@list.CategoryName"> @list.CategoryName </label>
    }
</div>
```

---

Below are my supplementary codes *and* issues.

#### Update 1

> **Error: (JsonReaderException: 'S' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.)**

This error was caused when `public string? CollectionCategory` was converted to `public List<string>? CollectionCategory` in *both* **Model** and **ViewModel**.

The error line was **line 33.** in my controller which worked fine when no `List<string>?` was used in **Model**. The cause is still unknown.

- Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var CardPostVM = new CardsViewModel
    {
        PostCard = await _context.Posts.ToListAsync()
    };

    var cached = _cache.TryGetValue("post", out var post);
    if (cached)
    {
        return View(post);
    }

    return View(CardPostVM);
}
```

- ViewModel

```
public class CardsViewModel
{
    public List<PostModel>? PostCard { get; set; }
    public List<CollectionModel>? CollectionCard { get; set; }
}
```

**[Json Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1kp5.jpg)**

---

#### Update 2

These are supplementary database files related to this issue

- ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    // Pages
    public DbSet<CollectionModel> Collections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PostModel> Posts { get; set; }

    // Category
    public DbSet<CollectionCategoryModel> CollectionCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PostCategoryModel> PostCategories { get; set; }
}
```

**Posts Database files:**

- PostRepository

```
public class PostRepository : IPostInterface
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public PostRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public bool Add(PostModel post)
    {
        _context.Add(post);
        return Save();
    }

    public bool Delete(PostModel post)
    {
        _context.Remove(post);
        return Save();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<PostModel>> GetAll()
    {
        return await _context.Posts.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<PostModel> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _context.Posts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
    }

    public async Task<PostModel> GetByIdAsyncNoTracking(int id)
    {
        return await _context.Posts.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
    }

    public bool Save()
    {
        var saved = _context.SaveChanges();
        return saved > 0 ? true : false;
    }

    public bool Update(PostModel post)
    {
        _context.Update(post);
        return Save();
    }
}
```

- IPostInterface

```
public interface IPostInterface
{
    Task<IEnumerable<PostModel>> GetAll();
    Task<PostModel> GetByIdAsync(int id);
    Task<PostModel> GetByIdAsyncNoTracking(int id);
    bool Add(PostModel post);
    bool Update(PostModel post);
    bool Delete(PostModel post);
    bool Save();
}
```

---

#### Update 3

> **Error: *[CS0029](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0029?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0029))***.

It arises when using `List< string>?` in **ViewModel** without using ***string.Join()*** in Controller. For further understanding, view the **[Solution]**

---

Thank you

Comment: What's your CardsViewModel ?

Comment: @QingGuo I have updated my CardsViewModel

Comment: How do you save your _context.Posts ? I guess  in your create action you may miss  `_context.Add(post); await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`

Comment: "It is on line 33. var CardPostVM = new CardsViewModel of PostController which was working fine!!!"  I don't meet the error like yours, what do you mean which was working fine? When do you get this error?

Comment: @QingGuo I got this error _after_ using `List<string>` method. The error disappears if I do not use it

Comment: Have a look at my update, we can try to use the `List<string>` in CreatePostViewModel, and keep PostModel still use `public string? CollectionCategory { get; set; }`

Comment: @QingGuo I used `name` instead of `asp-for` in my view while using still using  public List<string>? CollectionCategory { get; set; } in **PostModel**. The result is it still gives error ***JsonReaderException*** but it stopped blaming line 33.

Comment: @QingGuo I have updated **ApplicationDbContext** if it helps.

Comment: @QingGuo I have updated my `PostRepository` and `IPostInterface`

Answer (score 2):

Your model is set up to capture only a single string value for `CollectionCategory`. Change `CollectionCategory` in your `PostModel` to a `List<string>` to store multiple selected categories.

```
public class PostModel
{
    // Other properties before

    public List<string>? CollectionCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Update the `CreatePostViewModel` to use `List<string>` for `CollectionCategory`:

```
public class CreatePostViewModel
{
    // Other properties before

    // Category
    public List<string>? CollectionCategory { get; set; }

    // Category List
    public List<CollectionCategoryModel>? CollectionCategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Gives error **JsonReaderException: 'S' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.**

Comment: This error arises when you're trying to parse or read JSON data but the provided input is incorrect or not properly formatted JSON. On which line you got the error?

Comment: It is on line **33. var CardPostVM = new CardsViewModel** of `PostController` which was working fine!!!

Comment: But you didn't provide the above code in your OP.

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: I have also update the error Image

Comment: Can you also add the `CardPostVM`  class to the OP.

Comment: I have updated my CardsViewModel

Answer (score 2):

To save multiple checkbox value ,

PostModel

```
public class PostModel
{
    // Code before

      public List< string>? CollectionCategory { get; set; }
}
```

CreatePostViewModel

```
public class CreatePostViewModel
{
    public  List<string>? CollectionCategory { get; set; }

    // Category List
    public List<CollectionCategoryModel>? CollectionCategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

in the view you can try:

```
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.CollectionCategoryList.Count; i++)
  {
      <input type="checkbox" name="CollectionCategory[@i]" id="CollectionCategoryList[@i].CategoryName" value="@Model.CollectionCategoryList[@i].CategoryName">
      <label asp-for="CollectionCategory" for="Model.CollectionCategoryList[@i].CategoryName"> @Model.CollectionCategoryList[@i].CategoryName </label>
  }
```

result:

[image]

**Update:**

```
public class PostModel
{
    // Code before

    public string? CollectionCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your create :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreatePostViewModel postVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       for(var i=0;i< postVM.CollectionCategory.Count; i++)
{
    var post = new PostModel
    {
        // Code before             

        // Category
        CollectionCategory = postVM.CollectionCategory[i],
    };
       _context.Add(post); 
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        // Error
    }
    return View(postVM);
}
```

**Update 2**

You can also just save the name and Id from the CollectionCategoryList:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.CollectionCategoryList.Count; i++)
{
    <input type="hidden" name="CollectionCategoryList[@i].Id" value="@Model.CollectionCategoryList[@i].Id" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="CollectionCategoryList[@i].CategoryName" id="CollectionCategoryList[@i].CategoryName" value="@Model.CollectionCategoryList[@i].CategoryName">
    <label asp-for="CollectionCategory" for="Model.CollectionCategoryList[@i].CategoryName"> @Model.CollectionCategoryList[@i].CategoryName </label>
}
```

Then in the create action:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < postVM.CollectionCategoryList.Count; i++)
 {
     var post = new PostModel
     {
         // Code before             
         Id = postVM.CollectionCategoryList[i].Id,
         // Category
         CollectionCategory = postVM.CollectionCategoryList[i].CategoryName,
     };
     _context.Add(post);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
 }
```

Comment: Error: **'asp-for' must be of type 'System.Boolean' or 'System.String' that can be parsed as a 'System.Boolean' if 'type' is 'checkbox'.**

Comment: @ZNAXNOR  Try to use `name`  not `asp-for` when use type checkbox. like `<input type="checkbox" name="CollectionCategory[@i]" id="CollectionCategoryList[@i].CategoryName" value="@Model.CollectionCategoryList[@i].CategoryName">`

Comment: @ZNAXNOR  Have a look at my Update2. If my answer help you resolve your issue ?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?

Comment: I didn't use the View in **Update 2** because my code doesn't allow it instead using the View you first provided. It doesn't work. It still saves only one value regardless.

Comment: @ZNAXNOR  Have a try to not use `List< string>? CollectionCategory` just use `string CollectionCategory` in   PostModel, then try the  View in Update 2 . " my code doesn't allow it i" What do you mean don't allow it ? Do you get any error ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using _just_  `public string? CollectionCategory` without `List <string>?`. 

I do not want to store CollectionCategoryList Id in my PostModel Id as it can complicate my code in the future.

Comment: @ZNAXNOR  You can not  store CollectionCategoryList Id in my PostModel Id .I just for the test.

Comment: I tried the code. It gave error **SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Posts' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.**

Comment: @ZNAXNOR  " It still saves only one value regardless. " How do you save the post before?

Comment: I have posted the code in my question. Should I post my code whole? It worked for only one value and not multiple

Comment: @ZNAXNOR ," Should I post my code whole? It worked for only one value and not multiple –" From your post code , I don't see the data save to the database. In the Updated 2, you can set a breakpoint at  CreatePostViewModel postVM, you can get the selected  CategoryName, then do your other staff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256170/discussion-between-znaxnor-and-qing-guo).

Comment: @ZNAXNOR   have a look at my image, I can get two selected CategoryName, https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNgql.gif     note I use my update2 view.

Answer (score -1):

#### This is my solution

<sub>Special thanks to ***[@QingGuo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77604479/20763759)***</sub>

---

- ViewModel:

> **Converted *`string?`* to *`List< string>?`***

```cs
public class CreatePostViewModel
{
    // Code before
    
    // Category
    public List< string>? CollectionCategory { get; set; }

    // Category List
    public List<CollectionCategoryModel>? CollectionCategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

- Controller

> **Added *`string.Join()`***

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreatePostViewModel postVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var post = new PostModel
        {
            // Code before             

            // Category
            CollectionCategory = string.Join(',', postVM.CollectionCategory),
        };

         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        // Error
    }
    return View(postVM);
}
```

- View

> **Convert *`asp-for`* to *`name`* in `<input>` tag**

```
<div class="form-check">
    @foreach (var list in Model.CollectionCategoryList)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="CollectionCategory" id="@list.CategoryName" value="@list.CategoryName">
        <label asp-for="CollectionCategory" for="@list.CategoryName"> @list.CategoryName </label>

    }
</div>
```

---

Thank you!